# LCR Band Pass Filter in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, frequency-analysis

LCR Circuit:
[image: LCR Circuit]

Problem Description:
[image: Problem Description]

For my Signals and Systems class, we are supposed to use Python and matplotlib to plot the frequency responses of a variety of different circuits, including an LCR band pass filter.

Calculating the transfer function was easy, and can obviously be checked with a simple google search as $H(ω)=\frac{R}{\frac{1}{jωC}+jωL+R}$. In order to plot it, we were told to put it in terms of the frequency, and this is where I've run into trouble. I've tried several ways of getting the equations into terms without using R, L, or C, and my latest attempt has given me

```
def H(F):
    out = 1 / ((1j*2*np.pi*F / BW) + (w0**2 / (1j*2*np.pi*F*BW)) + 1)
    return out
```

To plot the function, I have this:

```
BW = 0.1 #The bandwidth in kHz
F0 = 21 #The resonant frequency in kHz
w0 = 2*np.pi*F0 #The resonant frequency in radians
F = np.arange(20.5,21.5, 0.1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5) )       #The size of the graph
plt.suptitle('Plot of the Magnitude of the Frequency Response of an LRC Band Pass Filter')  #The title of the graph
plt.plot(F,abs(H(F)))                  #The plotting of function
plt.ylabel('|H(F)|', color="blue")  #Labeling of the y axis
plt.xlabel('F kHz',horizontalalignment='right', x=1.0, color="blue")  #Labelling of the x axis
plt.yticks([0,1/np.sqrt(2),1], color="red")       #The values of the y axis
plt.xticks([21], color="red") #The values of the x axis
plt.grid(True)  #Shows the graph
```

Which outputs this:
[image: Plot]

I know this can't be correct, can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: You're only plotting 10 points.  That's a good representation of a bandpass filter with resolution that gross.  Perhaps you should use .01 in your `np.arange` call.

Comment: @TimRoberts Definitely an oversight on my part, which has been fixed. The function is still forming to almost a point, and doesn't at all line up with the half-power frequencies.

Comment: Since you're faking values of L, C, and R, why do you think the plot is not correct?  I would assert that you're now seeing a very sharp bandpass filter.